# Javascript Concatenate array string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string-concatenation

I'm kinda stuck in exercise for a couple of time, and I feel a little dumb because it seems quite easy lol. Here's all the data:

> Print the first element of the Vesper Martini array along with the string 'The first ingredient is: '

What I did so far: (the first line was already made)

```js
var vesperMartini = ['Gordons', 'vodka', 'Kina Lillet', 'ice', 'lemon peel'];
console.log ('The first ingredient is:'+ vesperMartini[1]);
```

The output:

```js
Output
>>>>Code is incorrect
Did you concatenate the string as required? The output should start with The first ingredient is:
The first ingredient is:vodka
```

I would be really glad if someone could help me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Array indexing starts at zero. First element is `vesperMartini[0]`

Comment: Array indexes start from `0`, not `1`

Comment: I'm guessing your unit tests may also be expecting a space after the `is:`

Comment: I tried everything that you've said but it keeps going on the same error

Comment: Use `"is: "`, with a space. That should work

Comment: It worked! in fact I tried it before, adding the space after de "is: " but it didn't work, somehow now it did. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

The array index of most of the programming languages starts at `0`. So you have to try the `0` index.

```
var vesperMartini = ['Gordons', 'vodka', 'Kina Lillet', 'ice', 'lemon peel'];
console.log ('The first ingredient is:'+ vesperMartini[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays start at index 0, not 1. `vesperMartini[0]` should do the trick.

For reference, this is known as [zero-based numbering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering).

Answer (score 0):

In JS index is counted from 0 not from 1, first element of any array has index 0

console.log ('The first ingredient is:'+ vesperMartini[0]);